# Rabbitmq crash when boot failed

Tags: rabbitmq

I meet a problem when booting rabbitmq which is driving me crazy...

Env:redhat4

erlang version:R16B03 installed from source code

rabbitmq version:rabbitmq-server-3.6.1 from source code

when I ran 'rabbitmq-server start' command, it gave me some error 
information, then I ran that again it showed:

```
              RabbitMQ 3.6.1. Copyright (C) 2007-2016 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@bogon.log
  ######  ##        /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@bogon-sasl.log
  ##########
              Starting broker...
```

And it stucked there, I thought may be it had started, so I ran './rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management' to enable web plugins, but I got:

```
The following plugins have been enabled:
  mochiweb
  webmachine
  rabbitmq_web_dispatch
  amqp_client
  rabbitmq_management_agent
  rabbitmq_management

Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@bogon... failed.
Error: {undef,[{crypto,module_info,[attributes],[]},
               {rabbit_misc,module_attributes,1,
                            [{file,"src/rabbit_misc.erl"},{line,805}]},
               {rabbit_misc,'-all_module_attributes/1-fun-0-',3,
                            [{file,"src/rabbit_misc.erl"},{line,825}]},
               {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1248}]},
               {rabbit_boot_steps,find_steps,1,
                                  [{file,"src/rabbit_boot_steps.erl"},
                                   {line,40}]},
               {rabbit_boot_steps,run_boot_steps,1,
                                  [{file,"src/rabbit_boot_steps.erl"},
                                   {line,26}]},
               {rabbit,start_apps,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,343}]},
               {rabbit_plugins,ensure,1,
                               [{file,"src/rabbit_plugins.erl"},{line,52}]}]}
```

I don't know why... so I stopped the rabbitmq server and started it again, and it gave me this:

```
              RabbitMQ 3.6.1. Copyright (C) 2007-2016 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@bogon.log
  ######  ##        /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@bogon-sasl.log
  ##########
              Starting broker...

BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {could_not_start,rabbit,
       {undef,
           [{crypto,module_info,[attributes],[]},
            {rabbit_misc,module_attributes,1,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_misc.erl"},{line,805}]},
            {rabbit_misc,'-all_module_attributes/1-fun-0-',3,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_misc.erl"},{line,825}]},
            {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1248}]},
            {rabbit_boot_steps,find_steps,1,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_boot_steps.erl"},{line,40}]},
            {rabbit_boot_steps,run_boot_steps,1,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_boot_steps.erl"},{line,26}]},
            {rabbit,start,2,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,477}]},
            {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,269}]}]}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@bogon.log
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@bogon-sasl.log

{"init terminating in do_boot",{could_not_start,rabbit,{undef,[{crypto,module_info,[attributes],[]},{rabbit_misc,module_attributes,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_misc.erl"},{line,805}]},{rabbit_misc,'-all_module_attributes/1-fun-0-',3,[{file,"src/rabbit_misc.erl"},{line,825}]},{lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1248}]},{rabbit_boot_steps,find_steps,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_boot_steps.erl"},{line,40}]},{rabbit_boot_steps,run_boot_steps,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_boot_steps.erl"},{line,26}]},{rabbit,start,2,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,477}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,269}]}]}}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

I don't understand... Why there are a lot of issues? Is there any procedure that was not correct?

Comment: provide the steps used for installing `rabbitmq`

Answer (score 2):

```
{could_not_start,rabbit,{undef,[{crypto,module_info,[attributes]
```

means that you need the `crypto` Erlang.

Check this https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html.

```
use SSL/TLS reliably    17.0
```

you need the version >= `17.0`

Comment: Thanks so so so much... It really worked... At first I used the latest erlang, but there were always core dumps, but this time it's Ok, I think may be it's because this time I use source code version of erlang&rabbitmq...

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue because of mismatch of RabbitMQ version installed on 3rd node other than two nodes. Install same versions on all nodes of cluster.