# why i got an error script after enable rabbitmq_management

Tags: rabbitmq

i was try to install and running rabbitmq in my windows and following the tutorial from the official web.
but i got an error script after run

> rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

in my command prompt
this is an error i have
[error script in rabbitmq_management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nLRh.png)

i was run rabbitmq service but it's no effect
and i cannot run http://localhost:15672
i think it's because management plugin error, how to fix the error script. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `undef crypto module` means that you don't have the `erlang crypo module` installed.

The `Management UI` requires this module.

You are maybe running an old `erlang` version.

Try to remove the the current version and download this version:

http://erlang.org/download/otp_win64_18.3.exe

Comment: yes i was downgrade my erlang version :D
thanks for help @Gabriele 
and i found the answer from here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267434/rabbitmq-crash-when-boot-failed

Comment: @egatejapratama that is always my answer :)! can you please accept the answer?